# Unable to index item: tcm:XXX Forbidden

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

we have upgraded SDL web 8 from Sdl Tridion 2013 SP1 and upgraded successfully,
As part of configure after the upgrade, i have run Sync-TcmSearchIndex. However it is not working for me. So I ran (Get-TcmRepository).ID | Sync-TcmSearchIndex -verbose with MTSUser credentials,it was ran successfully
we are getting below errors in Event Viewer post ran above command.

Unable to index item: tcm:xxxx-xxxxx. Forbidden

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing
Errorcode: 854
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

```
StackTrace Information Details:
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing.SearchIndexingEngine.ThrowIndexingException(String hostUrl, TcmUri subjectId, WebException e)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing.SearchIndexingEngine.AddToIndex(TcmUri subjectId)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchIndexer.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()
```

And we are unable to login http:\localhost:8983\tridion with MTSUser and we are getting below error
Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied

Content Manager MMC snap in,SDLSearchUsers group is available and
MTS User is a part of this group
we are able to login in CM server with MTSUser credentials

In Addition we are getting following error in event viewer
Unable to index item: tcm:xx-xxxxx. Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 - Error report

## HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied

**type** Status report

**message** Access to the requested resource has been denied

**description** Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.39

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing
Errorcode: 854
User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

StackTrace Information Details:
   at

```
Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing.SearchIndexingEngine.ThrowIndexingException(String hostUrl, TcmUri subjectId, WebException e)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.Indexing.SearchIndexingEngine.AddToIndex(TcmUri subjectId)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SearchIndexer.QueueMessageHandler.HandleMessage()
```

Could you please help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen similar error in the past and it occurred because of incorrect entries in "%TRIDION_HOME%solr-tomcat\conf\web.xml" for below nodes:

```
<security-role> 
<role-name>[MachineName]\SDLSearchUsers</role-name> 
</security-role> 
<auth-constraint> 
<role-name>[MachineName]\SDLSearchUsers</role-name> 
</auth-constraint>
```

Double check [MachineName] is correct in your CM server. Hope this helps!